# R: plot has no numbers on axis

Tags: r, plot, graph, label

Extremely basic question, given the code:

```
f_chi_squared <- function(x, r) {
  return ( (x^(r/2 - 1) * exp(1)^(-x/2)) / ( gamma(0.5*r) * 2^(r/2) ) )
}

this_chi_squared <- function(x) {
  return (f_chi_squared(x, 2))
}


plot(this_chi_squared)
```

I do not get any numbers on the X and Y axis.

[image]

I would like to have numbers on the x and y axis, and not have them blank like this.

I am using Rstudio. The problem appears when I plot discrete points too.

---

After adding `dev.off`

I get

```
Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) :
  cannot open compressed file '/tmp/RtmpQFaYTk/rs-graphics-32344720-c968-4c9e-b94a-0b9de3edf7db/.snapshot', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Graphics error: Plot rendering error
```

Comment: Probably you've inadvertently run some code overriding the default device options. Try running `dev.off()` to reset the device. If that doesn't work, restart R

Comment: Also `xlab` and `ylab` do not show

Comment: @Gregor Thanks, but I get this new error (added to question)

Comment: You got that error when you restarted R??

Comment: @Gregor I made the code more reproducible, the error comes when I run the code with `dev.off()` added

Comment: Okay, then let me point you to my earlier comment, *If that doesn't work, restart R*.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks for you valuable time and attention, I solved partially the problem by adding dev.off and restarting R. Now the only problem that remains is that the error at the bottom of my answer appears if I try to make 2 plots and try to go back from the second to the first using the back arrow. I will try to update my Rstudio to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your margin is too small. use following code before of `plot` :

```
par(mar = c(5,5,3,1))
```