# Y axis values missing in R scatter plot and graphs

Tags: r, graph, yaxis

I have been unable to get any graphs to show y-axis values in RStudio. My understanding is that the y-axis should set it self automatically. I've also attached an example of the data below. Do I need to be specifying the y-axis, or am I formatting my data incorrectly in some way?

```
homes = read.csv("~/Downloads/homePrice1.csv")
model = lm(homes$Price ~ homes$Size, 
           data = homes)
plot(homes$Price ~ homes$Size, 
     data = homes,
     xlab = "Size",
     ylab = "Price")
coeff=coefficients(model)
rSquare = summary(model)$r.squared
eq = paste0("y = ", round(coeff[2],5), "*x + ", round(coeff[1],2), "\nR^2 = ", round(rSquare*100,2), "%")
print(eq)
abline(model, lwd = 3, col = "darkorange")
text(x = 1500, y = 300000, label = eq)
```

[image: Graph without y-axis values]

[image: Data]

Answer (score 0):

I used `dev.off()` and that fixed the problem. I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52918211/r-plot-has-no-numbers-on-axis).